# Calculating the sum and product of a family of sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let's mark for $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$: $A_{n}$ = $\mathbb{N}$ \ {$n^2$}. Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the function $f(k) = k^2$.
Compute: $$\bigcap_{n ∈\mathbb{N}}f^{-1}(A_n)$$ $$\bigcup_{n ∈\mathbb{N}}f^{-1}(A_n)$$ 
I can't understand the connection between this function and set. Can someone help me with understanding?

Comment: You may be overthinking this.  Take it one step at a time.  What is $A_{13}$?  What is $A_{29}$?  Now calculate $f^{-1}(A_{13})$ and $f^{-1}(A_{29})$.  Use what you see as a guide to determine the requested intersection and union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we can look at what is the set $f^{-1}(A_n)$.
By definition, we get:
$f^{-1}(A_n)=\{ a~|~ (a^2=)f(a)\in A_n\}$, 
and (also by definition) $a^2 \in A_n \iff a^2\in \mathbb{N}~\land~a^2\neq n^2 \iff a\in \mathbb{N} ~\backslash~\{\pm n\}$. 
So we get $f^{-1}(A_n)=\mathbb{N} ~\backslash~\{\pm n\}$.

We get: (for $x\in\mathbb{N}$)
$x\in\bigcap_{n \in\mathbb{N}}f^{-1}(A_n)=\bigcap_{n \in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N} ~\backslash~\{-n,+n\}\iff \forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.x\neq\pm n\iff x\in\emptyset$

$x\in\bigcup_{n \in\mathbb{N}}f^{-1}(A_n)=\bigcup_{n \in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N} ~\backslash~\{-n,+n\}\iff \exists_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.x\neq\pm n\iff x\in\mathbb{N}$